# Open local files in MediaElement without using FileOpenPicker in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mediaelement

I want to play few specific files in my app using MediaElement. The files are stored in the assets folder. So I dont want to use the FileOpenPicker. I just want that when a button is clicked a file from the assets folder must be played. How can I set the source of the MediaElement to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Uri as the source which points to the file. Like, "Assets/MyMovie.mp4". This feature is described in better detail in the [`MediaElement` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement).